# FFT Not Getting Expected Results And Too Much Noise

Tags: matlab, fft

Here's my code:

```matlab
close all;clc;clear all;

f=fopen ('sum_021223.txt'); 
Adata=cell2mat(textscan(f, '%f %f %f %f %f'));

time=Adata(:,5);
data = Adata;
data(:,5:end) = 0;

final=size(data,1);
data(1,1)=data(2,1);

testsum=sum(data,2);


Fs = .5;            % Sampling frequency                    
T = 1/Fs;             % Sampling period       
L = final;             % Length of signal
t = (0:L-1)*T;  
t=t';

Y=fft(testsum)

P2 = abs(Y/L);
P1 = P2(1:L/2+1);
P1(2:end-1) = 2*P1(2:end-1);

f = Fs*(0:(L/2))/L;
% P1(1,1)=P1(2,1);

plot(f,P1) 
title("Single-Sided Amplitude Spectrum of X(t)")
xlabel("f (Hz)")
ylabel("|P1(f)|")
```

I believe I setup my code correct. I am sampling data once per 2 seconds. I have 30530 rows of data (About 17 hours worth)
However my FFT just looks like a bunch of noise, and I would expect some spikes around the smaller frequencies that would represent changes in air temperature and such over the day I took the data.

[image: FFT pic]

[The input data on Dropbox.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ib3qvktwm72mxsr/sum_021223.txt?dl=0)

I tried to set `P1(1,1)` to be equal to `P1(2,1)`. This somewhat helped, but not really.

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. Please read [ask]. It is unclear what your question is from a programming point of view. It seems to be a signal processing question.

Comment: I agree this is more of a question for https://dsp.stackexchange.com/ , it is not about programming. Did you plot the input data and noticed a clear repeating pattern that  you expect to detect in the frequency domain? Is the broad peak just below 0.1 Hz not what you expected?

Answer (score 0):

Your FFT looks corect, you have a very noisy data. You can maybe plot a power spectrum of that signal. You can distinguish different parts in the signal, here is function:

```
close all;clc;clear all;
f=fopen ('sum_021223.txt'); 
Adata=cell2mat(textscan(f, '%f %f %f %f %f'));

time=Adata(:,5);
data = Adata;
data(:,5:end) = 0;

final=size(data,1);
data(1,1)=data(2,1);

testsum=sum(data,2);


Fs = .5;            % Sampling frequency                    
T = 1/Fs;             % Sampling period       
L = numel(testsum);             % Length of signal
t = (0:L-1)*T;  
t=t';

[f,y]=MyPower(testsum,Fs);

plot(f,y) 
title("Single-Sided Amplitude Spectrum of X(t)")
xlabel("f (Hz)")
ylabel("|P1(f)|")
ylim([0,6e-3]);

 function [f,y]=MyPower(y,freq)
    tuReal = "seconds";
    samples=numel(y);
    period=1/freq;
    time=linspace(0,samples*period,samples)';

    signal=y;
    Fs=freq;
    % Compute effective sampling rate.
    tNumeric = time2num(time,tuReal);
    [Fs,irregular] = effectivefs(tNumeric);
    Ts = 1/Fs;

    % Resample non-uniform signals.
    x = signal;
    if irregular
        x = resample(x,tNumeric,Fs,'linear');
    end

    % Set Welch spectrum parameters.
    L = fix(length(x)/4.5);
    noverlap = fix(L*50/100);
    win = window(@hamming,L);

    % Compute the power spectrum.
    [ps,f] = pwelch(x,win,noverlap,[],Fs);
    w = 2*pi*f;

    % Convert frequency unit.
    factor = funitconv('rad/TimeUnit', 'Hz', 'seconds');
    w = factor*w;
    Fs = 2*pi*factor*Fs;

    % Remove frequencies above Nyquist frequency.
    I = w<=(Fs/2+1e4*eps);
    w = w(I);
    ps = ps(I);

    % Configure the computed spectrum.
    ps = table(w, ps, 'VariableNames', ["Frequency", "SpectrumData"]);
    ps.Properties.VariableUnits = ["Hz", ""];
    ps = addprop(ps, {'SampleFrequency'}, {'table'});
    ps.Properties.CustomProperties.SampleFrequency = Fs;
    f=ps.Frequency;
    y=ps.SpectrumData;
end
```